# Is there a DevOps methodology aimed towards academia and students?

Tags: culture, academia

I am still learning about DevOps, I wonder in Academia the workloads can often be quite heavy, I noticed there are variations on the DevOps methodology, e.g. DataOps and DevSecOps.

I wonder if there is something like StudentOps or similar to this especially targetted to the more scientific and computer science like subjects? I have noticed a similar question: [DevOps in research and science projects?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/6719) . But this does not explain why additionally one has not been developed for academia.

Comment: What should be the deliverable and the pipeline to it? X-ops does not actually make much sense to me. So if you automate a LaTeX paper script and data experiments linked to its figures could be one thing.

Comment: What is x-ops? I have now heard of this.

Comment: "X-Ops" is meant as X=younameit because some groups try to emphasize their specific part/aspect of lifecycle

Comment: Ah thought so. With the LaTeX thing I already automate this myself using overleaf and referencing as my studies is primarily software development automating results and the process can be very challenging and improbable.

Comment: Well ok in studies you do not have a real product, you focus on aspects here and there. For larger projects of course ci/cd and concepts like dependency mgmgt, iaas and testing make a lot of sense.

Comment: DevOps means a team made of Developers and Operators, it's an organization pattern. Who would be the Operators in your StudentOps, how would they differ in primary workload from the Sudents ?

Comment: No idea am new to devops

Comment: DevOps is more like a mindset, that a concrete methodology, If you process have conditions to Flow, Feedback and Experiment, you are doing DevOps even if you don't have any Devs and Ops departments.
I am strongly recommend you read [The Phoenix Project][1]

  [1]: https://www.amazon.com/Phoenix-Project-DevOps-Helping-Business/dp/0988262592

Pd: DevSecOps sucks. Security should be embedded in Dev and Ops, don't add a new complexity layer.

Comment: @SomeT Could you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a DevOps methodology aimed towards academia and students? No.

Comment: Should there be? Instead of having students ship software in zip files or on paper, have them commit code to a VCS that automatically kicks off a report to the TAs? It lets them work in “proper environments” right from the start.